# Why is this Javascript code generated by PHP not working?

Tags: javascript, php

All PHP generated Javascript Code I’ve done works, but this doesn’t … any idea?

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('$r');\">E-Mail an $row[firma] senden</a> &hellip;<br />\n";
```

I’ve tried everything … print <<<HTML, print <<<JS … other quotes (single quotes, no quotes) … it just executes an HTML link …

Comment: What is shown in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure - what's the value of $r and $row? Which part isn't working? What is the actual output of the markup, when you view the source? Are there any javascript errors in the Web Developer console?

I will make an assumption that `$r` and `$row` are valid PHP variables in this context, and that the `linkTo_UnCryptMailto()` javascript function exists.

I also note that the `firma` key is not enclosed in quotes - I am going to assume that's a typo.

Try simplifying the code and not parsing the variables within a "double quoted" string:

```php
echo '<a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto(' . $r . ')">E-Mail an ' . $row['firma'] . ' senden</a> &hellip;<br />';
```

Comment: If you need clarification of some points, they would be better suited to comments than part of an answer.

Comment: Thank you … I got it now … I just forgot to begin the string to encode with the phrase »mailto:« …